# How to make .desktop file work after mounting volumes

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.
I have a desktop shortcut that points to an application that is stored on VeraCrypted drive

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=KeePassXC
Exec=/mnt/z/linux/softy/keepassxc/KeePassXC-2.7.6-x86_64.AppImage
Icon=/mnt/z/linux/softy/keepassxc/keepassxc.svg
#comment=cloud
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Encoding=UTF-8
Categories=Utility;
```

This works fine when drives are mounted. When I start my descktop session, this mount point is not yet mounted, icon is shown as "broken" (shortcut does not work obviously). But when I mount that point, shortcut is still invalid. I have to open that .desktop file and save it even without any changes. Then Icon is visible again and shortcut works.

How can I make it to work without the need of "touching" it after mounting destination location?